# Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install

Tags: flutter, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to create a pipeline using gitlab and flutter application, I am able to build the app of Android but on IOS side i am facing problem from last 3 days and not able to find the root cause
I have tried everything to fix it .
Here the Logs which i am getting in gitlab CI/Cd Pipeline for IOS build

utomatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 2ZDU85TK2P
Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables

I have tired to uninstall the ruby version and install again .

#### My System Logs are:

ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]

pod env

Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.12.1
        Ruby : ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
    RubyGems : 3.4.16
        Host : macOS 13.4.1 (22F82)
       Xcode : 14.3.1 (14E300c)
         Git : git version 2.41.0
Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod
```

Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```